# Semaphore Wait vs WaitAsync in an async method

Tags: c#, concurrency, semaphore, synchronizationcontext

I'm trying to find out what is the difference between the SemaphoreSlim use of Wait and WaitAsync, used in this kind of context:

```
private SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(1);
public async Task<string> Get()
{
   // What's the difference between using Wait and WaitAsync here?
   this.semaphore.Wait(); // await this.semaphore.WaitAsync()

   string result;
   try {
     result = this.GetStringAsync();
   }
   finally {
     this.semaphore.Release();
   }

   return result;
}
```

Comment: Same as the difference between most other `XXX` and `XXXAsync` methods: one blocks while the other yields the thread.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you have async method - you want to avoid any blocking calls if possible. `SemaphoreSlim.Wait()` is a blocking call. So what will happen if you use `Wait()` and semaphore is not available at the moment? It will block the caller, which is very unexpected thing for async methods:

```
// this will _block_ despite calling async method and using await
// until semaphore is available
var myTask = Get();
var myString = await Get(); // will block also
```

If you use `WaitAsync` - it will not block the caller if semaphore is not available at the moment.

```
var myTask = Get();
// can continue with other things, even if semaphore is not available
```

Also you should beware to use regular locking mechanisms together with async\await. After doing this:

```
result = await this.GetStringAsync();
```

You may be on another thread after `await`, which means when you try to release the lock you acquired - it might fail, because you are trying to release it not from the same thread you acquired it. Note this is **NOT** the case for semaphore, because it does not have thread affinity (unlike other such constructs like `Monitor.Enter`, `ReaderWriterLock` and so on).

Comment: Semaphores are not thread-affine, so they can be acquired/released from any thread. Other locking mechanisms are thread-affine, though.

Answer (score 11):

The difference is that `Wait` blocks the current thread until semaphore is released, while `WaitAsync` does not.